# Eliminating redundant batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am new to batch and need some guidance on how to make my script shorter...
it works ok but theres alot of repeated lines .

The script sends 'arp -a' to temp file for parse then goes thorugh the 6 IP address to check if they are static or not .

Any advise to create shorter better method would greatly be appreciated . Thank-you !

---

```
@ECHO OFF

cls

ECHO ---------------Check SiteC IP = Static -----------------

ARP -a > O:\temp_log.txt

SET /A var1 = 0
SET /A var2 = 0
SET /A var3 = 0
SET /A var4 = 0
SET /A var5 = 0
SET /A var6 = 0


FOR /F "tokens=1,3 delims= " %%A IN ('findstr "static" "O:\temp_log.txt"') DO IF "%% A"=="192.168.0.11" ECHO %%A = %%B && SET /A var1 = 1 
IF %var1% == 1 ( ECHO Match ) ELSE ( ECHO SiteC1 FAIL )

ECHO --

FOR /F "tokens=1,3 delims= " %%A IN ('findstr "static" "O:\temp_log.txt"') DO IF "%%A"=="192.168.0.12" ECHO %%A = %%B && SET /A var2 = 1 
IF %var2% == 1 ( ECHO Match ) ELSE ( ECHO SiteC2 FAIL )

ECHO --

FOR /F "tokens=1,3 delims= " %%A IN ('findstr "static" "O:\temp_log.txt"') DO IF "%%A"=="192.168.0.13" ECHO %%A = %%B && SET /A var3 = 1 
IF %var3% == 1 ( ECHO Match ) ELSE ( ECHO SiteC2 FAIL )

ECHO --


FOR /F "tokens=1,3 delims= " %%A IN ('findstr "static" "O:\temp_log.txt"') DO IF "%%A"=="192.168.0.14" ECHO %%A = %%B && SET /A var4 = 1 
IF %var4% == 1 ( ECHO Match ) ELSE ( ECHO SiteC2 FAIL )

ECHO --

FOR /F "tokens=1,3 delims= " %%A IN ('findstr "static" "O:\temp_log.txt"') DO IF "%%A"=="192.168.0.15" ECHO %%A = %%B && SET /A var5 = 1 
IF %var5% == 1 ( ECHO Match ) ELSE ( ECHO SiteC5 FAIL )

ECHO --


FOR /F "tokens=1,3 delims= " %%A IN ('findstr "static" "O:\temp_log.txt"') DO IF "%%A"=="192.168.0.16" ECHO %%A = %%B && SET /A var6 = 1 
IF %var6% == 1 ( ECHO Match ) ELSE ( ECHO SiteC6 FAIL )


ECHO.
ECHO.

pause
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /l %%s IN (1,1,6) DO SET "var%%s=Site C%%s FAIL"
FOR /f %%A IN ('arp -a ^|findstr "static"') DO (
 FOR /l %%s IN (1,1,6) DO ( ECHO %%A
  IF %%A==192.168.0.1%%s SET var%%s=Site C%%s Match
 )
)
FOR /l %%s IN (1,1,6) DO CALL ECHO %%var%%s%%
GOTO :EOF
```

This should substitute.

The first FOR sets `VARn` to "Site Cn FAIL" for n=1 to 6.
The next FOR interprets the output of `ARP`, filtered for `"static"` The caret (`^`) before the pipe tells batch that the pipe is part of the command, not the `FOR`.
The neste FOR loops through the strings ``` 192.168.0.1`` to ```192.168.0.16`and if that matches the first token from the`ARP`output (in`%%A`)  then the appropriate variable is set to`...Match`

Finally, the contents of `var1`..`var6` are echoed.

There appears to be no reason for token 3, since %%B would only ever be "static", given your filter. Equally, space is a defult delimiter and none of the other defaults would occur in an `ARP` output line as fitered.

Comment: Thank- You for your help . This opened a whole new way of looking at my scripts .